# Why reference not kept when putting attribute on `this`?

Tags: javascript

Why the following code logs empty array, instead of the loaded array:

```js
function Car() {
  var parts = [];
  
  this.parts = parts;
  this.loadParts = loadParts;
  
  function loadParts() {
    parts = ['engine', 'wheels'];
  }
}

var audi = new Car();
audi.loadParts();
console.log(audi.parts);
```

(Trying to implement the reveal pattern)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your code reassign the local `parts` variable that it ends up pointing to a different array from `this.parts`.

A solution is to change the code to:

```
function loadParts() {
    parts.splice(0, parts.length, 'engine', 'wheels');
}
```

this will mutate in-place the content of the same array instead.

In Javascript the code

```
var x = [1, 2, 3];
var y = x;
x = [4, 5, 6]
```

will not change the content of what `y` is pointing to.

This is what your code is doing (with `y` being `this.parts`).

Answer (score 7):

You're manipulating the closed-over local variable `parts`, not `this.parts`

Update your code to:

```
function loadParts() {
  this.parts = ['engine', 'wheels'];
}
```

for more predictable results.

Comment: I'm trying to implement the revealing pattern. That's why I'm using `parts` instead of `this.parts`.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are overwriting the `parts` array with an entirely new array `parts = ['engine', 'wheels']`.

`this.parts` is a reference to the value of parts which is the original array `parts = [];`.

You either want to populate the original array:

```
function loadParts() {
    parts.push('engine');
    parts.push('wheels');
}
```

Or set the reference of `this.parts` to the new array

```
function loadParts() {
    parts = ['engine', 'wheels'];
    this.parts = parts;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

when you assign a value to an Object/Array, it will contain the reference of the value, and it looses its own references just like what you did here :

```
   this.parts = parts;
```

now when you did this :

```
  function loadParts() {
    parts = ['engine', 'wheels'];
  }
```

`parts` loses its own reference and its no longer equal to `this.parts`, I suggest you just push data to the `parts` array

```
  function loadParts() {
    parts.push('engine', 'wheels');
  }
```